# Set a selected value in a list of dropdowns jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I have a list of dropdowns that I am creating dynamically and giving the options of true and false to each one. Eventually, I am taking that data to the backend and moving it to the database. In this case, I cannot use the class to change the value because it is changing the values for all the elements and I cannot use Id because the Id is duplicated throughout the table and it changes the value of the first element.

Following is the code:

```
for (i in result) {
                    str += '<tr>';
                    for (j in result[i]) {
                        if (j == 6) {
                            str += '<td style="border-color: #FFD200; color:#D3D3D3"><select class="selTask" name="opts" value="' + result[i][j] + '">'
                            if (result[i][j] == true) {
                                str += '<option value= "true"> ' + result[i][j]+ ' </option>'
                                str += '<option value= "false"> false </option>'
                            } else {
                                str += '<option value= "false"> ' + result[i][j] + ' </option>'
                                str += '<option value= "true"> true </option>'
                            }
                            str += '</select></td>'
                        }
                        else if (j == 7) {
                            str += '<td id="usrLst" style="border-color: #FFD200; color:#D3D3D3"><select class="selUser" name="user" value="' + result[i][j] + '"><option value="' + result[i][j] + '">' + result[i][j] + '</option>'
                            for (p in userList) {
                                str += '<option value="' + userList[p] + '">' + userList[p] + '</option>'
                            }
                            str +='</select></td>'
                        }
                        else if (j == 8 || j == 9) {
                            str += '<td  style="border-color: #FFD200; color:#D3D3D3"><input type="text" class="value1" value="' + result[i][j] + '"/></td>'
                        } else {
                            str += '<td  style="border-color: #FFD200;">' + result[i][j] + '</td>'
                        }
                    }
                    str += '</tr>';
                }
```

Also, I cannot do anything on document.ready as the table is getting created dynamically.

My jQuery code looks something like below.

```
$(document).on('change', ".selTask", function () {
                    alert($(this).val())
                    var temp = $(this).val();
                });
```

The above code alerts proper value but I am not able to set that value to that particular column and row in the table.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I do see some issues: You have `value` on a `select`. You have two fields with the id of `stask`. And you have an `<input` inside your `select`.

Comment: That input is just to see if I can get the selected value. I am removing the <input which is inside the select. I have a value on select because I need the value which is coming from the database to display.

Comment: _"I cannot use Id because the Id is duplicated throughout the table"_ — it is invalid to have duplicate IDs in the DOM and it leads to unpredictable results. Commonly, as you experienced, either the first or last instance of an element using the ID will be found. I encourage you to fix that. You could do something conceptually like `id="sTask${j}"`

Comment: I am not using Id anywhere now, I removed them.

Comment: Update your question with your new code, so that way we can see what has been changed.

Comment: Updated the code

Comment: Now that is cleaned up, what element are you trying to fill in with `seltask`, is it `value1`?

Comment: No, with selTask I want to basically change the value of the selTask select option. So basically whatever option I select from the options in
' if (result[i][j] == true) {} ' should appear as a value in the <select>.

Comment: Or I just want that particular option tag under that particular select tag to have selected = "selected". So that I can differentiate with the nonupdated ones.